# Cant access my raspi web-server from outside my local network

Tags: networking, web-server, apache-httpd, port-forwarding

So I've been working on this problem for days now. I have the needed ports forwarded plus more opened just in case, I've tried changing **ports.conf** to listen to a different port for testing and still no results. I do see some people who have been through similar problems but none of the solutions have helped. Since I've never had problem port forwarding before I assume its not my router or ISP. If I try `netstat -tulpn | grep ":80"` I get this.

[image: Results from netstat -tulpn | grep ":80"]

These are the ports open on my network, As you can see I have more open then needed just because I have been trying many things out to get this to work. And the port 22 is for my SSH which does work outside my network. But this web-server doesn't. 192.168.0.156 is the address to my pi which is connected to the network through  WLAN. It's static and doesn't change.
[image: Ports open]

These are the firewall settings, I don't see much here so I assume its not the problem? Could, of course, be wrong.
[image: Firewall info]

This is an nmap scan I did to try and show if port 80 is open
[image: nmap info]

This is the ports file located in **/etc/apache2/ports.conf**
I did hear that some ISP's block port 80 so I have changed this to a different port before with the 000-default.conf file too. 
[image]

**000-default.conf file**
[image]

Comment: looks like your server is only listening on ipv6 - so port forwarding ipv4 won't help

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Instead paste the text direct into the question.

Comment: Does port forwarding only work for IPv4 addresses? So I have to make my server also listen to IPv4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some research I have found that my ISP blocks traffic from port 80. So port forwarding won't do much. What I am able to do is change the site to be hosted on port 8443. But since the default port that http is connected to is 80 that means I have to do **www.websitename.com:8443** every time to access it. Once my internet providers give me access to switching the (port block) off, on port 80 (which I think they will be adding it soon) then I should be fine with the apache default setting. But since I already changed my configuration to host it on 8443 I am thinking I can just redirect traffic to go from 80 to 8443 via port forwarding. But I will have to wait until I can unblock 80. This is what I've followed [THIS](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/287673/raspbian-apache-server-not-accessable-over-the-internet) to get the site hosted on 8443 but I did have to change some things because of the apache2 version I am using. Here are the changes I had to make.

**apache2/ports.conf**

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
        Listen 8443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
        Listen 8443
</IfModule>
```

**apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

**apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
    <VirtualHost _default_*:8443>
            ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

            DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

**apache2/apache.conf**

This goes at the bottom of the file

```
ServerName raspberrypi
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.